# How do I handle a long request in an MVC app

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, asp.net-mvc-4

So I have an MVC application in which an admin can log in, and upload a CSV of user detaisl (firstname/lastname/address/phone). This CSV is then imported into to the database.

This works fine for a small CSV, but not so much for one with lots of rows.

I was thinking it might be nice to do this task asynchronously, although I'd prefer not to process it in a scheduled task.

Also, I'd like to be able to poll the process with JavaScript to get a message of how the import is going. For example, after 10 secs, "3000 of 100000 subscribers have been imported".

How should I tackle this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick solution would be to process it in a **separate thread**. That will make sure that process is going without any effect to your current Web UI thread.

Another solution is somewhat similar that you have mentioned with [async controller.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

**Solution #2:** Look at this very useful post for a exact solution that you are asking for - [Need an ASP.NET MVC long running process with user feedback](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2927284/1437962).