# Asynchronous .NET MVC 4 Controller Action Method

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on a .NET MVC 4 web application. One of my ActionMethod takes long time (around 2 minutes) to finish the task and response back to client. I am calling this ActionMethod via JQuery AJAX call. Everything is working as expected but now I have to also display the current status of the ActionMethod. For example  weather method is "in progress" or "completed" or "failed" etc on client html page.

To achieve this task I found **AsyncController** class and read this article [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927284/need-an-asp-net-mvc-long-running-process-with-user-feedback), but I think this is very old way.

I need the latest and best approach to call a long running .NET MVC Action Method with user feedback on client.

Comment: Just update the DOM using jQuery.  "In progress" is set right before you send the ajax request, "completed" in the success handler, and "failed" in the error handler.

Comment: a jQuery ajax call is asynchronous by definition, so I don't think you need to change your Action,  just as suggested in the comment above you can use the $ajax :success and :error methods.

Comment: I think the key here is ***ActionMethod takes long time*** You should take a look at: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx