# Task.Factory.StartNew blocking calls to other methods during long running process

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await, task

I have a action method in ASP.NET MVC project (prod app) which imports csv file records and displays progress on progress bar, for this implementation i used this https://stackoverflow.com/a/2928148/1386991, this works well with brand new MVC project (poc app).

But, when I put exact same controller and view (with js code) in my original project (prod app), `CheckTaskProgress` methods hits only when `RunLongTask` completes the task hence users sees no progress bar update and sudden 100%, that's totally opposite behavior from what I had in brand new project (poc app). Here's visible behavior screenshot for your reference https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wNa5De0lmdA.

I checked MVC package versions and web.config, this looks fine. Any clue to check ?

Here's controller code:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Prod.Web.Controllers
{
    public class DemoController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> RunLongTask()
        {
            string id = "task_id1";  //should be unique
            int maxcount = 200;

            AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment();
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(taskId =>
            {
                HttpContext.Application["t_max_" + taskId] = maxcount;
                for (int i = 0; i < maxcount; i++)
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                    HttpContext.Application["t_prog_" + taskId] = i;
                }
                AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();
            }, id);

            return Json(new { status = true, ProgressCurrent = maxcount, ProgressMax = maxcount, ProgressPercent = 100 });
        }

        public ActionResult CheckTaskProgress()
        {
            string id = "task_id1";  //should be unique

            var progressCurrent = HttpContext.Application["t_prog_" + id];
            var progressMax = HttpContext.Application["t_max_" + id];
            decimal progressPercent = (Convert.ToDecimal(progressCurrent) / Convert.ToDecimal(progressMax)) * 100M;

            return Json(new
            {
                ProgressCurrent = progressCurrent,
                ProgressMax = progressMax,
                ProgressPercent = Convert.ToInt32(progressPercent)
            }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
}
```

And here's view with js code:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Run ajax long running process and display on progress bar";
}
<div class="main-wrap">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row py-5">
            <div class="col-12">
                <button class="btn btn-primary runlongtask">
                    <span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true" style="display:none;"></span>
                    Run ajax long running process and display on progress bar
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 pt-5">
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="0" style="width:0%"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@section foot{
    <script>
        $(function () {

            $('.runlongtask').click(function () {
                var triggerbtn = $(this);
                triggerbtn.prop('disabled', true).children('.spinner-border').show();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/demo/runlongtask',
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.status) {
                            longTaskUpdateProgress(data.ProgressCurrent, data.ProgressMax, data.ProgressPercent);
                            triggerbtn.prop('disabled', false).children('.spinner-border').hide();
                            window.clearInterval(longTaskInterval);
                        }
                    }
                });

                var longTaskInterval = window.setInterval(function () {
                    console.log('interval func invoked');
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: '/demo/checktaskprogress',
                        success: function (data) {
                            longTaskUpdateProgress(data.ProgressCurrent, data.ProgressMax, data.ProgressPercent);
                        }
                    });
                }, 5000);

                var longTaskUpdateProgress = function (ProgressCurrent, ProgressMax, ProgressPercent) {
                    console.log('progressbar func invoked');
                    $('.progress-bar')
                        .attr('aria-valuenow', ProgressPercent)
                        .css('width', ProgressPercent + '%')
                        .html(ProgressPercent + '% Completed');

                    console.log(ProgressPercent + ' Completed');
                    console.log(ProgressCurrent + ' executed out of ' + ProgressMax);
                };
            });

        })
    </script>
}
```

Here's the source code of my project (poc app) on GitHub https://github.com/itorian/Run-Ajax-Long-Process-With-Progress-Bar.

Comment: Have you tested `Task.Run` instead?

Comment: yes, this works several other places (in other controllers) in prod project.

Comment: They both return a Task, factory gives you more options on how you want that task created

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of possibilities:

1. Your existing project uses session state. If this is the case, you'll need to opt-out of session state for these methods; otherwise, the `CheckTaskProgress` call will block until `RunLongTask` completes, since it is waiting for the session to be available.
2. Your existing project [has not been updated for `async`/`await`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/all-about-httpruntime-targetframework/). If this is the case, you should add an appropriate `httpRuntime` `targetFramework` value.

Side notes:

- The answer you're using is from **two decades** ago. There are better solutions available today. SignalR, for example.
- This solution isn't going to work well in a web farm, since task statuses are all kept in-memory. A better solution is to store the task status in some shared place.
- You should avoid `StartNew`. I'm not even sure why it's in the original code; it should work the same without the `StartNew` and `AsyncManager` calls.

Comment: Thanks @Stephen, any recommended article for creating background task and getting its status to update on UI using SignalR?

Comment: What do you recommend between SignalR and Hangfire?

Comment: Either one is fine. SignalR supports distributed backplanes and Hangfire requires a database, so whichever one works for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Its not recommend to mix async and non async (blocking) code, so the following statement will cause you issues:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
```

Replace it with:

```
await Task.Delay(100);
```

> The rule of thumb is Async all the way down

Reference:
[When to use Task.Delay, when to use Thread.Sleep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082221/when-to-use-task-delay-when-to-use-thread-sleep)

Comment: Just used this in poc and prod projects, task immediately completes with 100% on progress in both projects :( you can try this with this poc project https://github.com/itorian/Run-Ajax-Long-Process-With-Progress-Bar

Comment: i need help to figure out why poc codes (https://github.com/itorian/Run-Ajax-Long-Process-With-Progress-Bar) not work as expected in prod project

Comment: This shouldn't make a difference at all.

Comment: @Tvde1 above changes creates bug on poc project

Comment: No, its uncovered another issue. You shouldn't mix blocking and non blocking code.

Comment: true, looks like i have issue with js code now, i can see progress, will update you.

Comment: FWIW; that actually doesn't matter here; StartNew starts a job running on another thread in the threadpool. The delegate passed in is not an async method so can't (and shouldn't) use `await`. Unless you change the delegate to be async. But, point is, it's not actually relevant as you jumping to another thread.

Comment: Remove of the System.Thread, highlighted that it didn't work as expected. That is, we are not passing something that returns a Task, just a delegate - hence this will not have the behaviour the op expected.