# Update UI with status updates while processing data in ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, background-process

I have a lengthy process which takes more than two hours. In order to prevent screen freeze, I do it as an AJAX request.

I am wondering whether there is any option to update my UI time to time so that user get status message?

Comment: Please post minimum reproducible code

Comment: what did you research so far? there are literally millions of hits on google for this problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need an ASP.NET MVC long running process with user feedback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927284/need-an-asp-net-mvc-long-running-process-with-user-feedback)

Comment: I need to post status message to UI about the progress of the process